# How to view a 100,000x100,000 massive image 30GB

Tags: memory, images, bmp, fractal

I've made a madnelbrot set generator in C and I've rendered a massive 100,000 square pixel image and its come out to be 30GBs big. My computer has 4GBs ram, how long should it take to load it?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you cut it up somehow?

Comment: You tell me, is it possible to cut up bmp images?

Comment: How did you store those 30GB in memory before rendering into a `.bmp`?

Comment: I;m sure there's a way to cut it up and render it in multiple files separately from the program - I don't know how though ~ sorry.

Comment: An optimisation I've made is to make a data file for every mandelbrot so that if I change the color or something then it loads really quickly and the data file for this was only 2GBs big

Comment: Could it be compressed using lossy compression. I imagine that fractal compression would probably do a good job.

Comment: I have to ask - do you *really* need to render such massive images? Can't you simply generate smaller versions that are far easier to handle?

Comment: did we really need to go to the moon? I was curious if I could make the image that big, I did, then I needed to view it so I had to go and do some learning, Its school holidays, I'm bored and curious.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to load an uncompressed 30GB bitmap with only 4GB of RAM.

There may be a program that exists, similar to a text editor that can view a portion of a file at once, that can stream and view a portion of this image without loading it in it's entirety. I don't know of any specifically though.

Comment: thats a bummer. Preview is trying very hard at the moment, would it be possible for a program like that to render a scaled down version and alow me to navigate it?

Comment: Well it could put it all on your page file (virtual memory) it's going to be painfully slow though...

Comment: thats good news. The data file took 1/2 a day and the file took a full day to write so if I can get it loaded in <Day then thats ok

Comment: I'd take Kyle's comment with a grain of salt. This is absolutely not feasible in the real world. If you want to scale it down, I'm sure there are plenty of programs that can do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this years ago, just checked and it was 7.5 gigapixels (yours is 10). Judging by what I wrote back then, it is possible to open such a large photo from within Photoshop, although mine created a 60GB temporary file, so you need some spare hard drive space.

I uplodaded it to a website dedicated to high resolution panoramas, although if you download similar software, it should hopefully work from your computer. Here's a link to the result I got, it's not the most ideal way of viewing a photo but it pretty much needs to be done for such large images - http://gigapan.com/gigapans/76165

Edit: Sorry, didn't quite realise how old the question was